# new page in pdf created by app

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6

I have an app that creates a report in a pdf form which works fine however the reports are now going over onto a second page. How do I start a new page?

The method used to generate the pdf is:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filepath), CGRectZero, nil)
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo (CGRectMake(0, 0, 792, 1122), nil)
```

*All the code for drawing the objects on the page*

```
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

I have tried using the `CGPDFContextBeginPage` but I am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo()` again to start a new page:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(...); 
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(...);
// ... code for drawing the first page ...
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(...);
// ... code for drawing the second page ...
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```